# $f(x) + f(-x)$ is aways even

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

I was having some troubles to help some friends with this question: Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. Is true that $g(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$ is aways symmetric to the $y$ axis? If $f$ is even or odd, this is trivial, but if the function is neither even or odd? When it is a polynomial neither ever or odd, it's pretty easy to see that this is true, but there is some function continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ that this is not true? If doesn't, how to prove that it is true for every $f$? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: -(-x) = x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$$

$$g(-x)=f(-x)+f(x)$$

Comment: That's it! I was trying to prove it with some continous function properties, but I realized that my friends won't understand that way! This was clean and straight to the point!

Comment: @GuilhermeNetto: $f$ can be as nasty as you want.

Comment: @GuilhermeNetto: also recall that $\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ is known as the even part of $f$, while the odd part is $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ .